# Subshell does not inherit PWD

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, pwd

Hi I am fairly new to Linux and I've been trying to SSH and CD in one line from Windows 10 into Ubuntu. One solution I thought to try was:

`ssh -t <ip address> "cd <directory>; bash"`

I've also tried:

`ssh -t <ip address> "cd <directory>; exec bash"`

However, I've had limited success. It seems that when `bash` or `exec bash` runs, the current working directory is not inherited for the subshell. This may be because of a company setting as I PXE boot my Linux machine.

In any case if I run this:

```
:~/l# cd ~/Desktop
:~/Desktop# exec bash
:~/l# pwd
/root/l
```

I see that executing bash resets my current working directory back to root. Is there a way to launch bash and set my cwd at the same time?

Comment: Maybe one of the rc files are changing into the home directory?  This doesn't happen on my systems.

Comment: @Jesse_b I see. I am guessing then something is set in my system from my PXE boot. I appreciate the additional information.

Comment: You could try: `ssh -t IP_ADDRESS 'cd DIRECTORY; bash --norc'`.  But that would probably give you an undesirable environment.  If it works it would be a clue that your issue is in the `.bashrc` file

Comment: @Jesse_b oh yeah that does work. I am not sure what environment variables I am missing now but that definitely confirms its based on the `.bashrc` file

Comment: Actually don't do that (my suggestion from my deleted comment), there could be some things that expect to be in the home directory to run and that would explain why it was put in there in the first place.

Comment: @Jesse_b oh shoot I just ran it I hope nothing got deleted

Comment: If you log in and try `cd ~/Desktop` and then run `bash` and it puts you back into `/root/l` you haven't changed anything

Comment: @Jesse_b yes it looks like everything is fine. For now I will be doing more research into `.bashrc` files. Thank you for everything.